Unable to See Lunch Targets for android-14.0.0_r52 on AWS Linux Instance
I am currently building AOSP on an AWS Linux instance. While working with the repository android-14.0.0_r28, I am able to see the list of lunch targets. However, for the repository android-14.0.0_r52, I am unable to see any lunch targets.
Here are the steps I have followed:

Initialized the repository with repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-14.0.0_r52
Synced the repository using repo sync
Attempted to list lunch targets with source build/envsetup.sh and lunch

Despite these steps, the lunch targets do not appear for android-14.0.0_r52.
Has anyone encountered a similar issue or can provide guidance on how to resolve this?
